# Does $\mathit{Suz}$ contain $M_{13}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, groupoids, sporadic-groups

$\newcommand\Suz{\mathit{Suz}}$I recently noticed that the Suzuki group $\Suz$ has as subgroups classes of both $L_3(3)$ and $M_{12}$, both of which are also subgroups of the Mathieu groupoid $M_{13}$. Additionally, $\lvert M_{13}\rvert$ divides $\lvert\Suz\rvert$. Could it be that $M_{13}$ embeds into $\Suz$?

Comment: Not familiar with groupoids, so I would be curious to see examples of a groupoid embedded into a finite group. (Other than subgroups of a finite group)

Comment: A necessary condition for a groupoid $(G,*)$ to embed into a group is that for all $a,b \in G$ then $a∗a^{−1}=b∗b^{−1}$. Is it true for $G=M_{13}$? If not, then $M_{13}$ cannot embed into a group, in particular $Suz$. Else, Thomas Connor and Dimitri Leemans may be able to help: https://leemans.dimitri.web.ulb.be/atlaslat/

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux $M_{13}$ can be constructed as a set of permutations on the 13 points of PG(2,3) and therefore embeds into the symmetric group $S_{13}$.

Comment: Interesting! What is the subgroup generated by $M_{13}$ in $S_{13}$?

Comment: If $M_{13}$ embeds in $S_{13}$ then for all $a,b \in M_{13}$ we should have $a * a^{-1} = b * b^{-1}$, right? But then, the groupoid $M_{13}$ should (as a small category) have a single object, and so should be a group, which is a contradiction. Where is the mistake in this argument?

Comment: Can you rephrase that to not involve category theory?

Comment: @DanielSebald: It should be possible to rephrase but I am not that familiar with groupoid theory. I wanted to be sure that I am not missing something about that so I posted the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4512531/84284 , but I am still unsure...

Comment: @DanielSebald: You should edit your post with your motivations and why do you expect such an embedding. It should help.

Comment: Your new edit makes me find this: *Generalizations of Lagrange and Sylow Theorems for Groupoids*, https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.07420

Comment: What does it even mean for a groupoid to embed in a group? $M_{13}$ may be defined in terms of permutation of 13 things, but that doesn't make it a subgroupoid (again, what even is that?) of $S_{13}$, because there are peculiar rules (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_groupoid#Construction).

Comment: @Daniel what Sebastien's post means is the set of units, namely $a\ast a^{-1}$ as $a$ varies over all elements of the groupoid, consists in fact of a single element, because this is true in a group, and if the groupoid is embedded in a group, the multiplication and inverses are respected. I believe the groupoid embeds in the _[action groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid#Group_action)_ of $S_{13}$ on the 13-element set used to build $M_{13}$, and not $S_{13}$ itself.